# Как создать таблицу с пустыми полями

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Мне нужно создать пустую таблицу на Readbeanphp. То есть описать названия полей и их типы.
Например:

```
 $table->Name = string;
 $table->Age = int;
```

Answer (score 1):

Readbeanphp при создании таблицы или столбца, автоматически устанавливает тип, в зависимости от записываемых данных. 
Ну а имена просто передайте обычным способом `$table->Name = 'Name';`

Comment: Мне это не подходит, мне нужно создать структуру таблицы, не записывая в нее данные.